# arm; VFP; Floating-point Extension; Undefined Instructions;

Tags: assembly, floating-point, arm, cortex-a

I have a device on ARM cortex-a9 and trying to implement "lazy float switching" for OS for this device. "lazy switching" is when

- VFP support is disabled,
- thread tries to execute any VFP instruction and generates exception,
- exception handler turn on VFP, manage thread context & return so the same instruction will be tried again,
- scheduler turns off VFP before switching threads.

The problem is that almost all VFP instructions generate synchronous exception when VFP is enabled.
Simply speaking

```
vadd.f32    s19, s19, s17
```

at first exception handler enables VFP and returns to retry `vadd.f32 s19, s19, s17`, the user-space code generates another exception

at second time generate synchronous exception. 
Exception Register, FPEXC is `FPEXC.EX == 0, FPEXC.EN == 1, FPEXC.DEX == 1`

And I could not understand what is the reason for this synchronous exception. I checked that

- Interrupts are disabled `FPSCR[15, 12-8] == 0`;
- VFPv3 is presented and implements full hardware FPU instruction set;
- `MVFR0` & `MVFR1` are also indicate that all features are implemented and software simulation is not required.

Any ideas what could be the reason of these extra exceptions?

PS:

apps are build w/ `-mcpu=cortex-a9 -marm -mfpu=vfpv3-fp16 -mfloat-abi=hard -ffast-math`;

`vpush...`, `vldr...` generate exception only when VFP is off (behave as expected)

Comment: I think you're saying that after your exception handler enables VFP and returns to retry `vadd.f32    s19, s19, s17`, the user-space code generates another exception.  It took me a while to figure out what *at first time make handler to turn on VFP* was saying, because it's so badly translated into English. :(  Please make an edit to improve that; feel free to copy my phrasing from the first sentence if I guessed right about what you're saying.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks, fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the Cortex-A9 FPU docs](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0408f/Ccdhcfga.html), the only reason for FPEXC.DEX to be set is if the thing was incorrectly configured to attempt short vector operations. The "V" in VFP has been deprecated since NEON came about, and isn't supported at all on anything newer than Cortex-A8.

You need to make sure that FPSCR.Len and FPSCR.Stride<sup>*</sup> are set to 0.

<sub>* OK, so strictly the value of Stride shouldn't matter when Len == 0, but hey, there's no good reason *not* to...</sub>

Comment: You're right. When Len & Stride are cleared inside handler, app works. From Reference Manual "ARM deprecates use of nonzero values of these fields". BTW Do you have any ideas how not zero values come into FPSCR.Len & FPSCR.Stride at first place? I regularly got them '7' & '3' respectively.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, did not clean storage buffer properly and restore FPSCR from some rubbish during switching.